# Large Blurs in SVG Filters not working in Safari

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

I've been using the following SVG filter in place of `filter: blur(#px);` for some time now as I need a blur that covers the element edge to edge as opposed to the usual fall off. It works wonderfully in Chrome on both desktop and Android.

Safari webkit on the other hand, has a variety of issues with it. I've experimented with removing and adjusting `feColorMatrix` and `feComposite` but the results worsen.

I've searched around for alternatives, but I've come up completely dry.

```
<filter id="ultraBlur" width="150%" height="150%" x="-25%" y="-25%" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="70"></feGaussianBlur>
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 9 0"></feColorMatrix>
    <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in"></feComposite>
</filter>
```

---

**as rendered by chrome**

---

[image: as rendered by chrome]

---

**as rendered by safari webkit**

---

[image: as rendered by safari webkit]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've run into a webkit memory management heuristic. From experimentation - the max blur size in a single pass is stdDeviation 45 on my sample image - greater than this and webkit downscales the image (to save memory - that's a huge blur).

Ok - you have two choices.

1. Force webkit to NOT downscale the image by adding a "filterRes="1200" to the filter element.
2. Separate out the blur into two steps to get the same effect.

I recommend strategy #2 - because filterRes is now deprecated and only works in iOS/Safari (because Apple is not keeping up with latest SVG things.) The following works just fine in iOS/Safari

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px">
  <defs>
  <filter id="ultraBlur" width="150%" height="150%" x="-25%" y="-25%" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="45"/>
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 10 0"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="45"/>
     <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 10 0"/>
    <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in"></feComposite>
</filter>
  </defs>
  <image filter="url(#ultraBlur)" x="0" y="0" width="700" height="400" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Paris-sunset-panoramic.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
</svg>
```